# How to place bootstrap 4 nav-item elements next to each other in mobile hamburger menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to place nav-item elements on mobile view in the hamburger menu next to each other. I photoshoped what I mean (no reputation to post images :/): https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhl0C.png

The Elements should be only next to each other on the  mobile!

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Amazing Website</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            My Products
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link " href="#">2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link " href="#">2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@media(max-width:767px) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; 
  }` on the parent element of the list items like so - https://codepen.io/bkdigital/pen/vYYBJJb

https://flexboxfroggy.com/ - This is a fun game to learn flexbox

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_flex.asp - This is to learn bootstrap 4 flex classes

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: Thank you the game is amazing ;) 

Also thanks for your answer. I was able to create it with bootstrap with `flex-flow: nowrap;`! Thank you! 

However now the items are quite small to click on touch devices: https://i.imgur.com/8rhoyq1.png

However do you know how we can fill the space?

Comment: Glad you liked the game and resolved your issue.Mark this as the correct answer please :) Also if you can put your code on codepen I can take a look at the other issue.

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons - This is how you increase the size of font awesome icons :)